# Chapter start on the right put text on the left

Tags: chapters, double-sided, scrbook

i'm using the classic thesis template.
(edit: Actually, i'm not loading the sty anywhere, so I guess I'm just using srcbook? the sty is however in the same folder...)

As many book templates chapters start on the right sided page in double page mode.
That is what I want.

However I would like to put text on the left page of that chapter starting page. In this case how to reference to this chapter.

How can I do this? So the text is linked with the chapter start.

I could mess arround with \clearpage, but this is a 'dirty' solution as this might jump every time i change the text...

Comment: Welcome, i think classicthesis is  'dirty' problem ;-p

Comment: @Johannes_B: Only 'dirty'? ;-)

Comment: How should it look like if the previous chapter ends on a left page? Would you like to have an empty right page then? This would be _really_ uncommon …

Comment: And [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) PS: I guess your question was down voted because you forgot to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ;-)

Comment: Thx and sorry I forgot the MWE. the text i want on the left page is side info on the chapter. If the previous chapter ends left, then the next should start on the right anyway, with the side info on the left... is that so uncommon?

Comment: @user77407: Well I’ve never seen something like this before … but as you see below ist is possible though …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you want to do.

You could use`\cleardoubleevenpage` to ensure that the additional informations are on the left page before the new chapter starts. But this may result in empty right pages before the additional informations as you can see on pages 1 and 7 in the following example.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\newcommand\chapterinfo[1]{\cleardoubleevenpage\thispagestyle{empty} #1}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapterinfo{Infos for the following chapter}
\chapter{A chapter}
\blindtext

\chapterinfo{Other informations for the second chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\Blindtext

\chapterinfo{\minisec{More information}Some explanations.}
\chapter{Next chapter}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

One can patch `\scr@startchapter` replace `\cleardoublepage` with `\mtcleardoublepage` and define `\mtcleardoublepage` to fill what one need.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*\mtleftpage{\hbox{}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mtcleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \mtleftpage\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\cleardoublepage}{\mtcleardoublepage}{}{\errmessage{error in patching \string\scr@startchapter}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\mtleftpage{some thing}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[1-2]
\renewcommand*\mtleftpage{onther thing}
\chapter{Three}
\lipsum[1-2]
\renewcommand*\mtleftpage{Bye}
\chapter{Four}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```